# which FD is garanteed to be satisfied by R?

Tags: relational-database, functional-dependencies

Pl explain the logic :
Let relation R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) satisfy the following functional dependencies:

```
A  → B, 
CH → A, 
B  → E, 
BD → C, 
EG → H, 
DE → F
```

Which of the following FDs is also guaranteed to be satisfied by R?

```
ACG → DH
CDE → AF
BCD → FH 
BED → CF
```

Comment: Show what you've figured out so far and where you're stuck.  Don't expect us to do all your work for you.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether a functional dependency is satisfied by R you need to take its left-hand side, calculate the closure with respect to the original set of the functional dependencies and then check whether the right-hand side is contained within the closure.

Example: Let us check whether `ACG → DH` is satisfied by R. We need to calculate the closure of `ACG`. Since `A  → B` we know that `B` should be in the closure of `ACG`. By the same token, since `B  → E` we know that `E` should also be in the closure of `ACG`. Moreover, since `E` is in the closure of `ACG` and trivially `G` is in the closure of `ACG`, `H` is also in the closure (`EG → H`). We stop here since no new attributes can be inferred and conclude that the closure of `ACG` is `ABCEGH`. However, `D` is not in the closure, so `DH` is not in the closure and therefore `ACG → DH` is not satisfied by R.

The remaining functional dependencies can be analysed in the same way.